# data.forEach is not a function when using Axios and creating a table with React-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-table

I am using react-table library along with axios to make the get call from api.   my use efft looks like this.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const result = await axios("http://site");
          setData(result.data)
        })();
      }, []);

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </div>
  );
```

I am however getting an error when trying to render the table.   The error that I am getting seems to be coming from my Table.js file

Error:
Table

```
src/Table.js:8
   5 | 
   6 | const [filterInput, setFilterInput] = useState("");
   7 | // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
>  8 | const {
     | ^   9 |   getTableProps,
  10 |   getTableBodyProps,
  11 |   headerGroups,
```

I am new to using react-table, any ideas why?  I did console.log the result and it is coming in as an object.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to render your data before it actually arrives. You need to do something, like `return data && (.../* the rest of your JSX */` to check whether the data is available before render.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I think you may be right, that passed by me the first time.  Whats a good way to do that in axios?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I check and the data is been set.

Comment: It's not about whether you get data or not, it's about ***when*** you get the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of a 'Loading' component which will render until your axios is complete and you have data to render. You could use it like this:

```
return !data.length ? (<div>Loading..</div>) : (<div className="App">
  <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
</div>)
```

Comment: it wasnt this, just checked and I am geting the data in the console.